# How to keep a copy of a dictionary with swapped items?

Tags: python, dictionary

The function `swap_elements` must swap elements in a `dict` and keep snapshots of the resulting `dict` before swapping back the elements to keep the original intact.

By example:

```
swap_elements({0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4]}, [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (0, 0))
```

Should return

```
{'entry 0': {0 :[2, 1], 1: [3, 4]},
 'entry 1': {0: [3, 2], 1: [1, 4]}
```

Here is the code.

```
def swap_elements(grid, new_positions, current_x_y):
    modified_grids_1 = {}
    i = 0
    # original = grid
    for pos in new_positions:
        # print(pos[0], pos[1], current_x_y[0], current_x_y[1])
        # print(grid[pos[0]][pos[1]], grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]])
        grid[pos[0]][pos[1]], grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]] = grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]], grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]
        # print_grid(grid)

        modified_grids_1.update({"entry "+str(i): grid})
        # print_grid(modified_grids[i])
        i += 1
        grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]], grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = grid[pos[0]][pos[1]], grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]]
        # print_grid(grid)
    print(modified_grids_1)
    # for k in modified_grids.keys():
    #     print_grid(modified_grids.get(k))
    return modified_grids_1
```

I get the changed grid value inserted rightly into `modified_grids_1` dictionary in for loop. But outside the for loop all the item values inserted in for loop gets back to the original value.

Comment: It's probably because first you are swapping the values and then you are unswapping them back to the original. Remove the line after `i += 1` ( starting with `grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]], grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = `) and check if thats fix it.

Comment: lets say i have a grid [7, 2, 4],[5 0 6],[8 3 1].Then blank tiles has position 1, 1.So it can swap with position (1, 2),(2, 1),(0, 1),(1, 0).new_positions has these 4 values right now.after swapping with the value in (1, 2), I add new grid configuration to the modified_grids_1 dictionary.Then I unswap the grid for next value in pos(2,1).Like this I get 4 grid configuration added in the modified dictionary in for loop. But outside the for loop I get every items(grids) in dictionary as its original value given at the time of calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that a `dict` is mutable. What you are trying to do is:

1. Swap two elements
2. Get a snapshot of the grid with swapped elements
3. Swap back the elements.

Although, if as snapshot you are using the same `dict` instead of a copy, when swapping back, you also swap the items in the snapshot.

What you should do instead is:

1. Make a copy of your grid
2. Swap the elements in the copy

To do this, use `copy.deepcopy`.

```
import copy

def swap_elements(grid, new_positions, current_x_y):
    modified_grids_1 = {}

    for i, pos in enumerate(new_positions):

        # Make a copy of the grid beforehand
        modified_grid = copy.deepcopy(grid)

        modified_grid[pos[0]][pos[1]], modified_grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]] = grid[current_x_y[0]][current_x_y[1]], grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]

        modified_grids_1["entry "+str(i)] = copy.deepcopy(modified_grid)

    print(modified_grids_1)

    return modified_grids_1

swap_elements({0: [1, 2]}, [(0,0)], (0, 1))  # {'entry 0': {0: [2, 1]}}
```

Note that I also added some improvements such as using `enumerate` to keep track of your entry number instead of an incremented variable and using item assignment instead of `dict.update`.